# What Is The Menu Launcher From KUbuntu 20.04?

Tags: kubuntu, plasma

I was running Kubuntu 20.04 LTS and the launcher looked like this:

[image: Kubuntu 20.04 Launcher]

I updated to 22.04 and it changed automatically and now looks like this:

[image: Kubuntu 22.04 Launcher]

What is the name of the launcher from 20.04 and how do I get it back?

Comment: I did try lots and couldn't find it, hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

These are plasma widgets. The widget you used before looks like `Favorites in a grid` or `Kickoff/Grid`.
https://store.kde.org/p/1317546/

In `Discover` go to `Plasma Addons`>`Plasma Widgets` and search for `favorites`[image]

Comment: This is very similar and is actually more customizable.

Answer (score 1):

In 20.04 it was the "Kickoff Application Launcher".
In 22.04 it is now the [Legacy Kickoff Application Launcher](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Kickoff/Legacy) as the version of the Plasma desktop has changed between Kubuntu releases.

> Legacy Kickoff was the default application launcher of the Plasma desktop before 5.21 release.

[image: Kickoff_Legacy_Menu_Style]